# limit of the function $x \to 1$

Tags: limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

Why $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1} \frac{ e^{ \frac{1}{\pi} \ln x } -1} {\frac{1}{\pi} \ln x }=1$$ 
I do not get it at all... I do not want explanation that would involve use of l'hospital rule

Comment: What is the term $f$?

Comment: apologise, just typo

Comment: Can you use Taylor series?

Comment: should be simpler solution

Comment: What's your definition of $e^y\,$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that $\lim_{x \to 0}\left(1 + x\right)^{1/x} = e$

Put $\ln y = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\ln x$. The limit becomes $$\lim\limits_{y\to 1}\dfrac{y-1}{\ln y}$$

$z=y-1$
$$\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\dfrac{z}{\ln (z+1)}$$

Also you can obtain 
$$\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{\ln(1 + z)}{z} = \lim_{z \to 0}\frac{1}{z}\ln(1 + z) = \lim_{z \to 0}\ln((1 + z)^\frac{1}{z}) = \ln e = 1$$

And that means your limit is also equal to $1$.

Comment: Probably, the OP will ask you how to prove that $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0}(1+x)^{1/x} = e$.

Comment: @AlexSilva I say, it is the definition of $e$ (slightly changed one).

Comment: I know, but due to a lot of restrictions imposed by the OP to solve this problem, I don't know if this limit is allowed.

Comment: It is, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Take $z = \frac{1}{\pi}\text{log}(x)$ and use the definition of derivative.

Comment: I am not allowed to use derivatives in this question

Comment: How do you want to solve this limit if you cannot use  l'Hopital, nor Taylor, nor definition of derivative (you should write this in your question body),...?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ the function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\ln x$. You have then $f(1)=0$

$\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\dfrac{e^{\frac{1}{\pi}\ln x}-1}{\dfrac{1}{\pi}\ln x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\dfrac{e^{f(x)}-e^{f(1)}}{f(x)-f(1)}$

Comment: Could you explain further, how does this allows me to show that lim=1?

Comment: $=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\dfrac{e^{f(x)}-e^{f(1)}}{x-1}\times\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}}$ Can you see it?

Comment: :o you're not allowed to use derivative. Then my answer isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Without using derivative:

Put $X=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\ln x$. When $x\to 1$, $X\to 0$. The limit becomes:

$\lim\limits_{X\to 0}\dfrac{e^X-1}{X}=1$.

Comment: How do you conclude this last fact?

Comment: Last year (last year at highschool) we studied it as a proposition equivalent to $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{ln(1+x)}{x}=1$ (well the last limit is proved by derivative).

Comment: And how do you prove that statement?

Comment: I edited my comment: (well the last limit is proved by derivative).

Comment: Ah, note that the OP doesn't want to use derivatives

Comment: Yeah... Problematic.